# Why is my convex hull algorithm returning the wrong points?

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry, maya, convex-hull

I'm writing some Python for Autodesk Maya that should return the 2D convex hull for a given 3D polygon.  More specifically, I want to flatten a 3D polygon by throwing out the height coordinates, and create a convex hull for the "flattened" 2D representation of said polygon.

For example, if it is given a list of vertices, the expected result should only be the vertices in the outermost edge loop.  There are a total of 400 vertices in a basic torus(just an example polygon), and the outer edge loop is made up of 20 of those vertices, but I end up getting 216 vertices back when calculating the convex hull; those vertices include ones that are in the innermost edge loops, which shouldn't happen.

The algorithm is based on code here:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain#Python

Note that I am using X and Z coordinates, not X and Y.  I don't think that this should be a problem as long as Z is used in the same way as Y, but correct me if I'm wrong.  You may also be wondering why I don't just look for vertices that have a height of 0; that would indeed work for the torus, but not for other polygons that are moving(animated) and do not have an "equator" that also happens to be the convex hull.

Here are some screenshots of the torus polygon.  The vertices highlighted in yellow are what I would expect the convex hull to be, given that we flattened the polygon by ignoring Y.

[image]
[image]

Here is a representation of my computed hull points.
[image]

As you can see, most of the vertices are selected.

Here is the code, though I re-wrote it so that it just takes arrays of vertex coordinates rather than depend on the Maya API.  Some things, like the Vertex class, may seem pointless here but that's because code was removed from the original version that doesn't have to do with the convex hull calculation.  Tested with Python 2.7.

```
class PolyFence(list):
  def __init__(self, vertices):
    self.compute_convex_hull(vertices)

  def intersects(self, polygon):
    for coordinate in self:
      if coordinate.within(polygon):
        return True 
    return False

  def compute_convex_hull(self, vertices):

    def cross(o, a, b):
      return (a.x - o.x) * (b.z - o.z) - (a.z - o.z) * (b.x - o.x)

    def build_hull(sorted_points):
      hull = []
      for p in sorted_points:
        while len(hull) >= 2 and cross(hull[-2], hull[-1], p) <= 0:
          hull.pop()
        hull.append(p)    
      return hull

    sorted_points = sorted(set(vertices))

    # Build lower hull 
    lower = build_hull(sorted_points)
    # Build upper hull
    upper = build_hull(reversed(sorted_points))

    c_hull_points = lower[:-1] + upper[:-1]

    ordered_hull_points = sorted(c_hull_points, key=lambda k: (-k.x, -k.z))
    ordered_hull_points[-2], ordered_hull_points[-1] = ordered_hull_points[-1], ordered_hull_points[-2]

    self += ordered_hull_points


class Vertex:
  def __init__(self, pair):
    self.x = pair[0]
    self.z = pair[1]
  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    if idx == 0:
      return self.x
    if idx == 1:
      # this is so we don't sort by values we aren't using
      return self.z
    return None

torus_coords = [(0.4755285680294037, -0.1545085906982422), (0.4045087695121765, -0.2938928008079529), (0.2938928008079529, -0.4045087397098541), (0.154508575797081, -0.4755285084247589), (0.0, -0.5000002384185791), (-0.154508575797081, -0.4755284786224365), (-0.2938927412033081, -0.40450865030288696), (-0.4045086205005646, -0.2938927114009857), (-0.47552838921546936, -0.1545085310935974), (-0.5000001192092896, 0.0), (-0.47552838921546936, 0.1545085310935974), (-0.4045085906982422, 0.29389268159866333), (-0.29389268159866333, 0.4045085608959198), (-0.1545085310935974, 0.4755283296108246), (-1.4901161193847656e-08, 0.5000000596046448), (0.15450848639011383, 0.4755282998085022), (0.29389262199401855, 0.4045085310935974), (0.404508501291275, 0.29389265179634094), (0.4755282700061798, 0.15450850129127502), (0.5, 0.0), (0.4988026022911072, -0.16207078099250793), (0.42430683970451355, -0.3082769513130188), (0.3082769513130188, -0.42430680990219116), (0.16207076609134674, -0.4988025426864624), (0.0, -0.5244719982147217), (-0.16207076609134674, -0.49880251288414), (-0.308276891708374, -0.424306720495224), (-0.4243066906929016, -0.30827686190605164), (-0.49880242347717285, -0.16207072138786316), (-0.5244718790054321, 0.0), (-0.49880242347717285, 0.16207072138786316), (-0.4243066608905792, 0.30827683210372925), (-0.30827683210372925, 0.42430663108825684), (-0.16207072138786316, 0.4988023638725281), (-1.5630476468686538e-08, 0.5244718194007874), (0.16207067668437958, 0.4988023340702057), (0.3082767724990845, 0.42430660128593445), (0.42430657148361206, 0.30827680230140686), (0.4988023042678833, 0.16207069158554077), (0.5244717597961426, 0.0), (0.5663464665412903, -0.1840171068906784), (0.48176309466362, -0.3500213325023651), (0.3500213325023651, -0.4817630648612976), (0.1840170919895172, -0.5663464069366455), (0.0, -0.5954918265342712), (-0.1840170919895172, -0.5663463473320007), (-0.35002127289772034, -0.48176294565200806), (-0.48176291584968567, -0.35002124309539795), (-0.5663462281227112, -0.18401704728603363), (-0.5954916477203369, 0.0), (-0.5663462281227112, 0.18401704728603363), (-0.4817628860473633, 0.35002121329307556), (-0.35002121329307556, 0.4817628562450409), (-0.18401704728603363, 0.5663461685180664), (-1.7747030511827688e-08, 0.5954915881156921), (0.18401698768138885, 0.5663461685180664), (0.3500211238861084, 0.4817627966403961), (0.48176276683807373, 0.3500211834907532), (0.5663461089134216, 0.18401700258255005), (0.5954915285110474, 0.0), (0.6715484857559204, -0.21819931268692017), (0.57125324010849, -0.4150397479534149), (0.4150397479534149, -0.57125324010849), (0.21819929778575897, -0.6715483665466309), (0.0, -0.7061077356338501), (-0.21819929778575897, -0.6715483069419861), (-0.41503965854644775, -0.5712530612945557), (-0.5712530612945557, -0.41503962874412537), (-0.6715481877326965, -0.218199223279953), (-0.7061075568199158, 0.0), (-0.6715481877326965, 0.218199223279953), (-0.5712530016899109, 0.4150395691394806), (-0.4150395691394806, 0.5712529420852661), (-0.218199223279953, 0.6715481281280518), (-2.1043639719664498e-08, 0.7061074376106262), (0.21819916367530823, 0.671548068523407), (0.4150395095348358, 0.5712529420852661), (0.5712528824806213, 0.4150395393371582), (0.671548068523407, 0.21819917857646942), (0.7061073780059814, 0.0), (0.8041107654571533, -0.2612714171409607), (0.6840174794197083, -0.49696773290634155), (0.49696773290634155, -0.6840174198150635), (0.2612713873386383, -0.8041106462478638), (0.0, -0.8454919457435608), (-0.2612713873386383, -0.804110586643219), (-0.4969676434993744, -0.6840173006057739), (-0.6840172410011292, -0.4969675838947296), (-0.8041104674339294, -0.26127129793167114), (-0.8454917073249817, 0.0), (-0.8041104674339294, 0.26127129793167114), (-0.6840171813964844, 0.4969675540924072), (-0.4969675540924072, 0.6840171217918396), (-0.26127129793167114, 0.8041103482246399), (-2.5197611108751516e-08, 0.8454916477203369), (0.26127123832702637, 0.8041102886199951), (0.4969674348831177, 0.6840170621871948), (0.68401700258255, 0.49696749448776245), (0.8041102290153503, 0.26127126812934875), (0.8454915285110474, 0.0), (0.9510571360588074, -0.3090171813964844), (0.809017539024353, -0.5877856016159058), (0.5877856016159058, -0.8090174794197083), (0.309017151594162, -0.9510570168495178), (0.0, -1.0000004768371582), (-0.309017151594162, -0.951056957244873), (-0.5877854824066162, -0.8090173006057739), (-0.8090172410011292, -0.5877854228019714), (-0.9510567784309387, -0.3090170621871948), (-1.000000238418579, 0.0), (-0.9510567784309387, 0.3090170621871948), (-0.8090171813964844, 0.5877853631973267), (-0.5877853631973267, 0.8090171217918396), (-0.3090170621871948, 0.9510566592216492), (-2.9802322387695312e-08, 1.0000001192092896), (0.30901697278022766, 0.9510565996170044), (0.5877852439880371, 0.8090170621871948), (0.80901700258255, 0.5877853035926819), (0.9510565400123596, 0.30901700258255005), (1.0, 0.0), (1.098003625869751, -0.35676300525665283), (0.9340177178382874, -0.6786035299301147), (0.6786035299301147, -0.9340176582336426), (0.35676294565200806, -1.0980035066604614), (0.0, -1.15450918674469), (-0.35676294565200806, -1.0980033874511719), (-0.6786034107208252, -0.9340174198150635), (-0.9340173602104187, -0.6786032915115356), (-1.0980032682418823, -0.3567628562450409), (-1.1545088291168213, 0.0), (-1.0980032682418823, 0.3567628562450409), (-0.9340173006057739, 0.6786032319068909), (-0.6786032319068909, 0.9340172410011292), (-0.3567628562450409, 1.0980030298233032), (-3.440703721935279e-08, 1.1545087099075317), (0.35676273703575134, 1.0980030298233032), (0.6786031126976013, 0.9340171217918396), (0.9340170621871948, 0.6786031723022461), (1.0980029106140137, 0.3567627966403961), (1.1545085906982422, 0.0), (1.2305657863616943, -0.3998350501060486), (1.0467817783355713, -0.7605314254760742), (0.7605314254760742, -1.0467817783355713), (0.3998350203037262, -1.2305656671524048), (0.0, -1.2938932180404663), (-0.3998350203037262, -1.2305655479431152), (-0.7605313062667847, -1.0467815399169922), (-1.0467814207077026, -0.7605312466621399), (-1.2305653095245361, -0.39983490109443665), (-1.2938929796218872, 0.0), (-1.2305653095245361, 0.39983490109443665), (-1.0467814207077026, 0.7605311274528503), (-0.7605311274528503, 1.046781301498413), (-0.39983490109443665, 1.2305651903152466), (-3.856100505572613e-08, 1.293892741203308), (0.3998347818851471, 1.230565071105957), (0.7605310082435608, 1.0467811822891235), (1.0467811822891235, 0.7605310678482056), (1.230565071105957, 0.3998348116874695), (1.2938926219940186, 0.0), (1.3357678651809692, -0.4340173006057739), (1.1362720727920532, -0.8255499005317688), (0.8255499005317688, -1.1362719535827637), (0.43401724100112915, -1.3357677459716797), (0.0, -1.4045093059539795), (-0.43401724100112915, -1.3357676267623901), (-0.8255497813224792, -1.1362717151641846), (-1.1362717151641846, -0.8255496621131897), (-1.335767388343811, -0.4340171217918396), (-1.4045089483261108, 0.0), (-1.335767388343811, 0.4340171217918396), (-1.136271595954895, 0.8255496025085449), (-0.8255496025085449, 1.1362714767456055), (-0.4340171217918396, 1.3357672691345215), (-4.1857617816276615e-08, 1.4045087099075317), (0.43401700258255005, 1.335767149925232), (0.8255494236946106, 1.136271357536316), (1.136271357536316, 0.8255494832992554), (1.3357670307159424, 0.43401703238487244), (1.4045085906982422, 0.0), (1.4033117294311523, -0.4559636116027832), (1.1937283277511597, -0.8672943115234375), (0.8672943115234375, -1.1937282085418701), (0.4559635818004608, -1.4033116102218628), (0.0, -1.4755290746688843), (-0.4559635818004608, -1.4033114910125732), (-0.8672941327095032, -1.193727970123291), (-1.1937278509140015, -0.8672940731048584), (-1.4033112525939941, -0.4559634327888489), (-1.4755287170410156, 0.0), (-1.4033112525939941, 0.4559634327888489), (-1.1937278509140015, 0.8672939538955688), (-0.8672939538955688, 1.193727731704712), (-0.4559634327888489, 1.403311014175415), (-4.3974171859417766e-08, 1.4755284786224365), (0.4559633135795593, 1.403311014175415), (0.8672937750816345, 1.1937276124954224), (1.1937274932861328, 0.8672938942909241), (1.4033108949661255, 0.4559633433818817), (1.475528359413147, 0.0), (1.4265857934951782, -0.46352580189704895), (1.2135263681411743, -0.8816784620285034), (0.8816784620285034, -1.2135263681411743), (0.46352577209472656, -1.4265856742858887), (0.0, -1.5000008344650269), (-0.46352577209472656, -1.4265855550765991), (-0.8816782832145691, -1.2135260105133057), (-1.2135260105133057, -0.8816782236099243), (-1.42658531665802, -0.4635256230831146), (-1.5000004768371582, 0.0), (-1.42658531665802, 0.4635256230831146), (-1.2135258913040161, 0.8816781044006348), (-0.8816781044006348, 1.2135257720947266), (-0.4635256230831146, 1.426585078239441), (-4.470348713425665e-08, 1.5000003576278687), (0.4635255038738251, 1.4265849590301514), (0.8816779255867004, 1.213525652885437), (1.213525652885437, 0.88167804479599), (1.4265849590301514, 0.46352553367614746), (1.5000001192092896, 0.0), (1.4033117294311523, -0.4559636116027832), (1.1937283277511597, -0.8672943115234375), (0.8672943115234375, -1.1937282085418701), (0.4559635818004608, -1.4033116102218628), (0.0, -1.4755290746688843), (-0.4559635818004608, -1.4033114910125732), (-0.8672941327095032, -1.193727970123291), (-1.1937278509140015, -0.8672940731048584), (-1.4033112525939941, -0.4559634327888489), (-1.4755287170410156, 0.0), (-1.4033112525939941, 0.4559634327888489), (-1.1937278509140015, 0.8672939538955688), (-0.8672939538955688, 1.193727731704712), (-0.4559634327888489, 1.403311014175415), (-4.3974171859417766e-08, 1.4755284786224365), (0.4559633135795593, 1.403311014175415), (0.8672937750816345, 1.1937276124954224), (1.1937274932861328, 0.8672938942909241), (1.4033108949661255, 0.4559633433818817), (1.475528359413147, 0.0), (1.3357678651809692, -0.4340173006057739), (1.1362720727920532, -0.8255499005317688), (0.8255499005317688, -1.1362719535827637), (0.43401724100112915, -1.3357677459716797), (0.0, -1.4045093059539795), (-0.43401724100112915, -1.3357676267623901), (-0.8255497813224792, -1.1362717151641846), (-1.1362717151641846, -0.8255496621131897), (-1.335767388343811, -0.4340171217918396), (-1.4045089483261108, 0.0), (-1.335767388343811, 0.4340171217918396), (-1.136271595954895, 0.8255496025085449), (-0.8255496025085449, 1.1362714767456055), (-0.4340171217918396, 1.3357672691345215), (-4.1857617816276615e-08, 1.4045087099075317), (0.43401700258255005, 1.335767149925232), (0.8255494236946106, 1.136271357536316), (1.136271357536316, 0.8255494832992554), (1.3357670307159424, 0.43401703238487244), (1.4045085906982422, 0.0), (1.2305659055709839, -0.39983507990837097), (1.0467818975448608, -0.7605315446853638), (0.7605315446853638, -1.0467818975448608), (0.3998350501060486, -1.2305657863616943), (0.0, -1.2938933372497559), (-0.3998350501060486, -1.2305656671524048), (-0.7605313658714294, -1.0467816591262817), (-1.0467815399169922, -0.7605313062667847), (-1.2305654287338257, -0.39983493089675903), (-1.2938930988311768, 0.0), (-1.2305654287338257, 0.39983493089675903), (-1.0467814207077026, 0.7605311870574951), (-0.7605311870574951, 1.0467814207077026), (-0.39983493089675903, 1.2305653095245361), (-3.8561008608439806e-08, 1.2938928604125977), (0.3998348116874695, 1.2305651903152466), (0.7605310678482056, 1.046781301498413), (1.0467811822891235, 0.7605311274528503), (1.2305651903152466, 0.39983487129211426), (1.293892741203308, 0.0), (1.098003625869751, -0.35676300525665283), (0.9340177178382874, -0.6786035299301147), (0.6786035299301147, -0.9340176582336426), (0.35676294565200806, -1.0980035066604614), (0.0, -1.15450918674469), (-0.35676294565200806, -1.0980033874511719), (-0.6786034107208252, -0.9340174198150635), (-0.9340173602104187, -0.6786032915115356), (-1.0980032682418823, -0.3567628562450409), (-1.1545088291168213, 0.0), (-1.0980032682418823, 0.3567628562450409), (-0.9340173006057739, 0.6786032319068909), (-0.6786032319068909, 0.9340172410011292), (-0.3567628562450409, 1.0980030298233032), (-3.440703721935279e-08, 1.1545087099075317), (0.35676273703575134, 1.0980030298233032), (0.6786031126976013, 0.9340171217918396), (0.9340170621871948, 0.6786031723022461), (1.0980029106140137, 0.3567627966403961), (1.1545085906982422, 0.0), (0.9510571360588074, -0.3090171813964844), (0.809017539024353, -0.5877856016159058), (0.5877856016159058, -0.8090174794197083), (0.309017151594162, -0.9510570168495178), (0.0, -1.0000004768371582), (-0.309017151594162, -0.951056957244873), (-0.5877854824066162, -0.8090173006057739), (-0.8090172410011292, -0.5877854228019714), (-0.9510567784309387, -0.3090170621871948), (-1.000000238418579, 0.0), (-0.9510567784309387, 0.3090170621871948), (-0.8090171813964844, 0.5877853631973267), (-0.5877853631973267, 0.8090171217918396), (-0.3090170621871948, 0.9510566592216492), (-2.9802322387695312e-08, 1.0000001192092896), (0.30901697278022766, 0.9510565996170044), (0.5877852439880371, 0.8090170621871948), (0.80901700258255, 0.5877853035926819), (0.9510565400123596, 0.30901700258255005), (1.0, 0.0), (0.8041106462478638, -0.2612713575363159), (0.6840173602104187, -0.4969676733016968), (0.4969676733016968, -0.6840173006057739), (0.2612713575363159, -0.8041105270385742), (0.0, -0.8454918265342712), (-0.2612713575363159, -0.8041104674339294), (-0.4969675838947296, -0.6840171813964844), (-0.6840171217918396, -0.49696752429008484), (-0.8041103482246399, -0.26127126812934875), (-0.8454915881156921, 0.0), (-0.8041103482246399, 0.26127126812934875), (-0.6840170621871948, 0.49696746468544006), (-0.49696746468544006, 0.68401700258255), (-0.26127126812934875, 0.8041102290153503), (-2.5197607556037838e-08, 0.8454915285110474), (0.261271208524704, 0.8041101694107056), (0.4969673752784729, 0.68401700258255), (0.6840169429779053, 0.4969674348831177), (0.8041101098060608, 0.261271208524704), (0.8454914093017578, 0.0), (0.6715483069419861, -0.2181992530822754), (0.5712531208992004, -0.41503965854644775), (0.41503965854644775, -0.5712530612945557), (0.2181992381811142, -0.6715481877326965), (0.0, -0.7061075568199158), (-0.2181992381811142, -0.6715481877326965), (-0.4150395691394806, -0.5712529420852661), (-0.5712528824806213, -0.4150395095348358), (-0.6715480089187622, -0.21819917857646942), (-0.7061073780059814, 0.0), (-0.6715480089187622, 0.21819917857646942), (-0.5712528824806213, 0.4150394797325134), (-0.4150394797325134, 0.5712528228759766), (-0.21819917857646942, 0.6715479493141174), (-2.104363439059398e-08, 0.7061072587966919), (0.21819910407066345, 0.6715478897094727), (0.41503939032554626, 0.5712527632713318), (0.571252703666687, 0.41503942012786865), (0.6715478897094727, 0.21819913387298584), (0.7061071991920471, 0.0), (0.5663461685180664, -0.18401701748371124), (0.4817628562450409, -0.3500211834907532), (0.3500211834907532, -0.4817628264427185), (0.18401700258255005, -0.5663461089134216), (0.0, -0.5954915285110474), (-0.18401700258255005, -0.5663460493087769), (-0.350021094083786, -0.48176270723342896), (-0.48176267743110657, -0.3500210642814636), (-0.5663459897041321, -0.18401695787906647), (-0.595491349697113, 0.0), (-0.5663459897041321, 0.18401695787906647), (-0.4817626476287842, 0.35002103447914124), (-0.35002103447914124, 0.4817625880241394), (-0.18401695787906647, 0.5663458704948425), (-1.774702163004349e-08, 0.5954912900924683), (0.1840168982744217, 0.5663458704948425), (0.3500209450721741, 0.481762558221817), (0.48176252841949463, 0.35002100467681885), (0.5663458108901978, 0.18401691317558289), (0.5954912304878235, 0.0), (0.4988022744655609, -0.16207067668437958), (0.42430657148361206, -0.3082767426967621), (0.3082767426967621, -0.4243065416812897), (0.16207066178321838, -0.49880221486091614), (0.0, -0.524471640586853), (-0.16207066178321838, -0.49880218505859375), (-0.3082766830921173, -0.4243064522743225), (-0.42430639266967773, -0.3082766532897949), (-0.4988020956516266, -0.1620706170797348), (-0.5244715213775635, 0.0), (-0.4988020956516266, 0.1620706170797348), (-0.42430636286735535, 0.30827662348747253), (-0.30827662348747253, 0.42430633306503296), (-0.1620706170797348, 0.4988020062446594), (-1.5630465810545502e-08, 0.5244714617729187), (0.16207057237625122, 0.49880197644233704), (0.30827656388282776, 0.42430630326271057), (0.4243062734603882, 0.30827659368515015), (0.49880194664001465, 0.16207058727741241), (0.5244714021682739, 0.0)]
torus        = [Vertex(coord) for coord in torus_coords]

fence = PolyFence(torus)

expectation_coords = [(1.4265857934951782, -0.46352580189704895), (1.2135263681411743, -0.8816784620285034), (0.8816784620285034, -1.2135263681411743), (0.46352577209472656, -1.4265856742858887), (0.0, -1.5000008344650269), (-0.46352577209472656, -1.4265855550765991), (-0.8816782832145691, -1.2135260105133057), (-1.2135260105133057, -0.8816782236099243), (-1.42658531665802, -0.4635256230831146), (-1.5000004768371582, 0.0), (-1.42658531665802, 0.4635256230831146), (-1.2135258913040161, 0.8816781044006348), (-0.8816781044006348, 1.2135257720947266), (-0.4635256230831146, 1.426585078239441), (-4.470348713425665e-08, 1.5000003576278687), (0.4635255038738251, 1.4265849590301514), (0.8816779255867004, 1.213525652885437), (1.213525652885437, 0.88167804479599), (1.4265849590301514, 0.46352553367614746), (1.5000001192092896, 0.0)] # 
expectation        = [Vertex(coord) for coord in expectation_coords]


assert(sorted(fence) == sorted(expectation))
```

Comment: The code looks good though if your getting more points then expected, you could try changing the while loop from `... <= 0` to `... < 0`. This excludes points that are on the edge of the convex hull. If that doesn't help, post images of what you are seeing VS what you expect to see (plots of 2D coordinates (x,z) for both should work nicely).

Comment: "the 2D convex hull for a given 3D polygon" is not defined. As you are just ignoring the Y coordinates, you are indeed computing the 2D convex hull of a 2D polygon, which may not be what you intended.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Actually, that's what I intend.  Basically, I need an "aerial view" outline of a 3D polygon, so I would expect that given only the X/Z data of the polygon(a 2D representation of the polygon), I should be able to get a convex hull representing said outline.

Comment: Can we see a picture of the XZ polygon ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have edited my question to include screenshots of the polygon.  The one of the top view is the XZ representation.

Comment: Why on Earth do you want to compute the convex hull when you know what vertices are on the equator ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Keep in mind that the torus is a simplistic example being used as a test.  I'm going to be using this code on moving objects that may not have an "equator" of uniform vertices of the same height.  If it can't even compute the convex hull of a torus, there's clearly a serious problem; it should at least be able to do the simplest thing.  Also, I am aware that I could use existing libraries like Scipy, but I do not wish to.

Comment: can you show the computed convex hull ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I've added a representation of the computed hull points.

Comment: aren't this just all the vertices ?

Comment: No, it isn't all of them, but it is most of them.  Notice how some of them are missing in the lower-left quadrant.

Comment: I don't see how your use of `sorted()` would produce lexicographically sorted points, given that you haven't provided a comparison operator. Try manually specifying a key function to `sorted()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Sneftel was right; my code wasn't actually sorting the points lexographically because my vertices are not lists or tuples, which are ordered per-property by Python.

This is how I changed the call to `sorted` to get the correct result:

```
sorted_points = sorted(set(self.vertices()), key=lambda v: (v.x(), v.z()))
```

Basically, I'm translating my object to a tuple for it to have something to sort by.

And here's the result. :)

[image]